# One to One mapping of 2 Table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, outer-join

- I have two tables `Order` and `Product`.
- Both tables have one `ID` field, 3 `feature` fields, and one `Date` field.
- I want to create an output table that can help me map from the `Order` table to the `Product` table.
- The conditions to satisfy are:

  - the order should match all the 3 features with the Product and should be a one-one mapping.
  - The `Delivery Date` of the `Product` should be before the `Order` date.

Please see the screenshots for an example:

[image]

I tried using `left join` but I am getting one order mapped to multiple products.

I need to have the one-one mapping of an order to a single product in such a way that the `delivery date` is before the `order date`.

Please advise how to write this SQL query.

```
SELECT
    [order].[id],
    product.[id]
FROM
    [order] 
    LEFT JOIN [product] ON
        [order].[feature1] = [product].[feature1]
        AND
        [order].[feature2] = [product].[feature2]
        AND
        [order].[feature3] = [product].[feature3] /*mapping all the 3 features*/
WHERE
    [order].[Order date] > [product].[Delivery date]
```

Comment: Please use a single SQL tag for the **exact** RDBMS you're using (I'm guessing MS SQL Server?).

Comment: What is the meaning of `Product.DeliveryDate`, exactly? Does the `Products` table represent SKUs or does it represent Order items? If it does not represent order-items then where is your `OrderItems` table? You should not be using separate columns to represent order-items, that's just bad database design and demonstrates a lack of normalization.

Comment: Hi @Dai, thanks for all the help. Product.DeliveryDate represents the date by which the products are manufactured by the company. The orders table represents the customer orders received by the company. So, the delivery date should fall before the order date to fulfill the shipment.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform inner join between order and product tables on F1, F2 and F3 columns and then filter results based on dates.

Sql Fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=371f403974b6751c0011f92fe4e76493).
Working sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #order (OrderId INT NOT NULL, F1 char(1) NOT NULL, F2 char(1)  NOT NULL, F3 char(1)  NOT NULL, OrderDate [date] NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE #product (ProductId INT NOT NULL, F1 char(1) NOT NULL, F2 char(1)  NOT NULL, F3 char(1)  NOT NULL, DeliveryDate [date] NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #order (OrderId, F1, F2, F3, OrderDate) 
    Values (1, 'A', 'D', 'G', '01 Feb 2021'), (2, 'A', 'E', 'G', '02 Apr 2021'), (3, 'B', 'D', 'H', '03 May 2021'),(4, 'B', 'E', 'H', '04 Jun 2021')

INSERT INTO #product (ProductId, F1, F2, F3, DeliveryDate) 
    values  (1, 'A', 'D', 'G', '15 Feb 2021'), (2, 'A', 'E', 'H', '16 Feb 2021'), (3, 'A', 'E', 'G', '17 Feb 2021')
          , (4, 'B', 'D', 'G', '18 Feb 2021'), (5, 'B', 'E', 'G', '19 Feb 2021'), (6, 'B', 'D', 'H', '20 Jun 2021')
          , (7, 'B', 'E', 'H', '21 Jul 2021'), (8, 'A', 'D', 'G', '01 Jan 2021'), (9, 'B', 'E', 'H', '21 Feb 2021')
          , (10, 'B', 'D', 'H', '20 Feb 2021')
select * from #order
select * from #product

select o.OrderId, p.ProductId from #order o join #product p on o.F1 = p.f1 and o.f2 = p.f2 and o.f3 = p.f3
where o.OrderDate > p.DeliveryDate
```

**Updating the last SQL statement to address the comments of OP**:

```
select o.OrderId, rp.ProductId 
    from #order o 
    --join #product p on o.F1 = p.f1 and o.f2 = p.f2 and o.f3 = p.f3
    join (SELECT  *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY f1,f2, f3  ORDER BY DeliveryDate ASC ) AS [DenseRank]  FROM #product) as rp on o.F1 = rp.f1 and o.f2 = rp.f2 and o.f3 = rp.f3
where o.OrderDate > rp.DeliveryDate and rp.DenseRank = 1

-- Or the same can be achieved via CTE
;WITH Ranked_Products (ProductId, F1, F2, F3, DeliveryDate, [version]) AS
(select  ProductId, F1, F2, F3, DeliveryDate, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY f1,f2, f3  ORDER BY DeliveryDate ASC ) AS [Version]  FROM #product)
select o.OrderId, rp.ProductId 
    from #order o
    join Ranked_Products as rp on o.F1 = rp.f1 and o.f2 = rp.f2 and o.f3 = rp.f3
where o.OrderDate > rp.DeliveryDate and rp.[version] = 1
```

Updated fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=46d91b5fb1f36ecdcf8cc08be4e6e0ec)

Update#2: Use one of the below approaches to get desired output.

```
-- Aproach #1
;with orders_products(OrderId, ProductId, f1, f2, f3, OrderDate, DeliveryDate, [version]) as
(
    select o.OrderId as OrderId, p.ProductId as ProductId, o.f1 as f1, o.f2 as f2, o.f3 as f3, o.OrderDate as OrderDate, p.DeliveryDate as DeliveryDate, (DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY o.f1,o.f2, o.f3  ORDER BY o.OrderDate asc, p.DeliveryDate asc)) as [version]
         from #order o 
         join #product p 
                on o.F1 = p.f1 and o.f2 = p.f2 and o.f3 = p.f3
    where o.OrderDate > p.DeliveryDate
)
select OrderId, ProductId from orders_products where [version] = 1

-- Aproach #2
select ro.OrderId, rp.ProductId 
    --from #order o 
    from (SELECT  *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY f1,f2, f3  ORDER BY orderdate asc ) AS [DenseRank]  FROM #order) as ro 
    --join #product p on o.F1 = p.f1 and o.f2 = p.f2 and o.f3 = p.f3
    join (SELECT  *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY f1,f2, f3  ORDER BY DeliveryDate ASC ) AS [DenseRank]  FROM #product) as rp on ro.F1 = rp.f1 and ro.f2 = rp.f2 and ro.f3 = rp.f3
where ro.OrderDate > rp.DeliveryDate and rp.DenseRank = 1 and ro.DenseRank = 1

-- Or the same can be achieved via CTE (Aproach #3)
;WITH Ranked_Products (ProductId, F1, F2, F3, DeliveryDate, [version]) AS
(select  ProductId, F1, F2, F3, DeliveryDate, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY f1,f2, f3  ORDER BY DeliveryDate ASC ) AS [Version]  FROM #product),
ranked_orders (OrderId, F1, F2, F3, OrderDate, [version]) AS
(SELECT  *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY f1,f2, f3  ORDER BY orderdate asc ) AS [DenseRank]  FROM #order)
select ro.OrderId, rp.ProductId 
    from ranked_orders ro
    join Ranked_Products as rp on ro.F1 = rp.f1 and ro.f2 = rp.f2 and ro.f3 = rp.f3
where ro.OrderDate > rp.DeliveryDate and rp.[version] = 1 and ro.[version] = 1
```

Updated fiddler [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8e74bd0243107a4222a7451994690ce7).

Comment: Hi @Sam, Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, this query fails to satisfy the one-one condition. For example. if we add another product matching to the combination of order 1 with the delivery date before the order date, this will give 2 output for order 1.  Try adding another product (11, 'A', 'D', 'G', '05 Jan 2021'), then order 1 will show multiple combinations. (Product 8 and 11). Ideally, order 1 should give one output (Product 8).

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=080fbfab1c62bfb4af89f4f50d305062

Comment: Thanks. but if another order ((5, 'B', 'E', 'H', '05 Jun 2021') comes in with the same set of features of a previous order then the product should be assigned based on the priority of their order dates. That condition is not satisfied. Updated fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4bb340904c4009515294582a26711d87

Comment: @Sreenivas You can use similar dense_rank query for orders also before joining. I will post the updated fiddle shortly. Meanwhile when there is an order with same set of features which order are you looking in resultset - 4 & 9  OR 5 & 9?

Comment: for 2 orders with the same combination of features, they will get assigned to the product which has the earliest delivery date. Ideally, the first ordered product should get the first delivered product, and the second ordered product should get the second delivered product.  Ideally Order 4 will get assigned to Product 9 and Order 5 will get assigned to Product 12. Updated Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=59b9f781915e6a1b734312b79abdf839

Comment: @Sreenivas Can you update the question by listing out all these conditions.